# no error messeage so i don't know what is wrong

Tags: lua

I was writing a code and i ran it but it didn't work. it didn't show me error messages so i don't know what is wrong. Could anyone fix this?

Here's the code.

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
value = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m",
    "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
            
function makepassword(v)
 for i = 1, v do
  local v = math.random(1, 35)
  local ud = math.random(0, 1)
  if ud == 1 then
   local p = string.upper(value[v])
  else
   local p = value[v]
  end
  if(not a) then
   a = p
  else
   a = a..p
 end
 return a
end

start = makepassword(18)
print(start)
```

Please help me.

Comment: I do get an error message from this. How are you running the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unclosed `for` operator, that's why it doesn't work. But just closing it wouldn't be enough. Here are some ways of tweaking the code further:

```lua
math.randomseed(os.time())

-- a little more compact way of storing character sets is strings:
local charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789"
-- store the length not to calculate it every time:
local charset_length = string.len(charset)

function makepassword(length) -- here was duplicated variable name v
    local a = "" -- no reason to use global a
    for i = 1, length do
        local v = math.random(1, charset_length)
        a = a .. charset:sub(v, v)
    end
    return a
end

start = makepassword(18)
print(start)
```

To be honest I don't like too much characters coded this way. There is Lua function string.char() which gives you a character from its code, like `string.char(48) == "0"`, `string.char(65) == "A"`, etc. So if you don't avoid special chars intentionally, it all can be much more simple:

```lua
function makepassword(length)
    local a = ""
    for i = 1, length do
        a = a .. string.char(math.random(33, 126))
    end
    return a
end

print(makepassword(18))
```

Welcome :)